# Can not correct echo content of file

Tags: php, echo

I'm fairly new to PHP and am having difficulty getting a plain text file to echo into an area.

```
$string = "";

if(isset($_POST['submitText']))
{
    if($_FILES){
        if($_FILES['file']['name'] != "") {
            if(isset($_FILES) && $_FILES['file']['type'] != 'text/plain') {
                echo "<span>File could not be accepted ! Please upload any '*.txt' file.</span>";
                exit();
            } 

            // echo "<center><span id='Content'>Contents of ".$_FILES['file']['name']." File</span></center>";

            $fileName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

            $file = fopen($fileName,"r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

            while(!feof($file)) {
            echo fgets($file). "";
            }

            while(!feof($file)) {
            $string = fgetc($file);
            // echo $string;
            }
       fclose($file);
       }
    }
}

<textarea name="string" value="" rows="10" columns="90" placeholder="Paste your text here or upload" id="" style="" ><?php echo $string; ?>
</textarea> 
<input type="file" name="file" size="60" style="" onchange="myFunction()"/>
<input type="submit" name="submitText" value="Read Contents" style=""/>
```

Does anyone have any clues or insights to which they could help? I have checked similar questions but not really give me an answer. I am aware of the // before echo' this was for testing.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop should read all of the file and just echo the contents out, so when the second loop tries to read the file, it will not run at all and `$string` will always be empty.

To read a file, rather than the various loops you have, you should do...

```
$string = file_get_contents($file);
```

This replaces all of the code from the `fopen()` and the two loops.